# Can't read files from mounted iso

Tags: 16.04, mount, iso, 16.10

Recently I came across a kind of new iso files which are not readable when mounted. Mount operation shows no errors, but directory listing looks like this:

```
?DirectoryName1/file_name1
?DirectoryName1/file_name2
?DirectoryName1/file_name3
?DirectoryName1/file_name4
...

?DirectoryNameN/file_name1
?DirectoryNameN/file_name2
?DirectoryNameN/file_name3
?DirectoryNameN/file_name4
```

I.e., all files are shown in root directory.

The `isoinfo -d -i myiso.iso` reports the following:

```
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: 
Volume id: label1          
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: 
Application id: 
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 159676
Joliet with UCS level 3 found
NO Rock Ridge present
```

Is it just `Joliet with UCS level 3 found` which is not supported?

p.s. Winrar on windows extracts it fine.

Comment: What does `file myiso.iso` tell you? BTW, both of the working `.iso`s (for other uses) I have are `Joliet with UCS level 3`.

Comment: It says `badiso.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'label1'`. Nothing outstanding.